# How to find source file path by compiled class file programmatically in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin, package can be declared randomly, which is not relative to source file path, then compiler will generate class file in package folder. How to find source file path by compiled class file programmatically?

Example:

```
package kt.notsamepackage_another

class NotSamePackageKotlin {

    fun call() {
    }
}
```

NotSamePackageKotlin.class will be generated in folder: ../kt/notsamepackage_another, but source file may be in ../kt/notsamepackage.

I tried these methods:

1. decompile class file. But source file path can't be found in byte code
2. adjust kotlin compiler parameters. I want find a parameter to output a mapping contains path relationship, but nothing was found
3. traverse source folder recursively. This method is not efficient, it's the last choice.

Is there any method more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  If the full source path isn't compiled into the bytecode, then there's no way to find it programmatically.  And I'm not aware of any compiler parameters which would do this.  (The simple filename is often compiled in, of course; that's how stack traces can show the filename and line number at which an exception was thrown.  But not the full path.)

Even your third method won't work in general; programs aren't usually run on the same machine on which they were compiled, so your code would have to make some very risky assumptions.

But I'm curious as to why you'd want to know this at all.  What problem are you trying to solve?